# Loosing special characters from Model property

Tags: struts2

I am using struts-2.3.16.3 for my application. My action implements the “ModelDriven” interface. Using interceptor reference as defaultStack.

The problem that i am facing is, all the special characters (non keyboard characters like ®, ℗) are disappearing from my model property by the time they reach to  my action class. Other special characters like @ # $ etc able to see those in my action.

Do i need to configure any other interceptors in the stack?. Help needed if i am missing in configuration.

Example: If i enter Piracy℗symbol in my text field, in action class when i print property value it shows Piracysymbol.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [showing-special-character-®-in-stextfield](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28094856/1700321).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have not mentioned the content-type. Try putting 
`<%@ page contentType=”text/html;charset=UTF-8″ %>` tag in your code if you haven't already. If the problem still persists write your code like this
 `<s:text name="username"/> <s:property value="getText('username')"/>`
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hai Rai,I tried with option 1 and it does not work for me. Placed in the jsp where i am sending my value to action class. And with option 2 i have s:textfield and does not work with it by using s:property. Please suggest.

Comment: Rai/All.. Any suggestion to fix this issue.